# Binary Search Tree insert function failing to add a new node to the tree

Tags: python, insert, binary-search-tree

I'm writing code to implement a Binary Search Tree in Python. I ran into problems in writing the `insert` function, which should add a new node at the correct in order location in the tree. I wrote it in two different ways: `insertNode1` works fine (correctly performs an insert on the tree), but `insertNode2` does not perform the insertion properly.  When I Do InOrderTraversal for the tree using `insertNode1` and `insertNode2`, it turned out that the 'insertNode1' yields the full tree while the 'insertNode2' only yields the root.

Why is it that `insertNode1` succeeds while `insertNode2` fails, and what are the meaningful differences between the two functions that cause this to be the case?

Here's my code:

```
def insert(self,val):
    if not self.root:
      self.root = TreeNode(val)
    else:
      self.insertNode2(self.root, val)

  def insertNode1(self,node, val):
    if val < node.val:
      if not node.left:
        node.left = TreeNode(val)
      else:
        self.insertNode1(node.left,val)
    else:
      if not node.right:
        node.right = TreeNode(val)
      else:
        self.insertNode1(node.right, val)

  def insertNode2(self, node, val):
    if not node:
      node = TreeNode(val)
    else:
      if node.val > val:
        self.insertNode2(node.left, val)
      else:
        self.insertNode2(node.right, val)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "InsertNode2 does not work"? Please provide the output and your expected output.

Comment: While a main/driver would be nice, this seems like an adequate question and mcve, more or less. It's not the clearest question by any stretch of the imagination and I'm not a fan of "does not work" as a problem statement, but enough code was provided that the problem is quite obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`insertNode2` doesn't correctly perform an insertion as expected because of the line `node = TreeNode(val)`, which makes a purely local assignment to `node`. This new object is never set to its parent `.left` or `.right` property and is lost when the function returns. The root node will not be modified in any run of this function.

Either use the already-working `insertNode1`, or add a `return node` statement to `insertNode2` and make an assignment in the parent function call scope to the new child.

Here's a snippet demonstrating how that might be done:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class BinarySearchTree:
    @staticmethod
    def p(root, depth=0):
        if root:
            print(" " * depth + str(root.val))
            BinarySearchTree.p(root.left, depth + 2)
            BinarySearchTree.p(root.right, depth + 2)

    @staticmethod
    def insert(node, val):
        if not node:
            return TreeNode(val)    
        elif node.val > val:
            node.left = BinarySearchTree.insert(node.left, val)
        else:
            node.right = BinarySearchTree.insert(node.right, val)

        return node

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = TreeNode(5)

    for n in [2, 1, 3, 7, 9, 6]:
        BinarySearchTree.insert(root, n)

    BinarySearchTree.p(root)
```

Output:

```
5
  2
    1
    3
  7
    6
    9
```

Which amounts to:

[image: tree]

Comment: Thanks for your Answers! Why the insertNode1 does not need the return node but the insertNode2 dpes?

Comment: The `insertNode1` function does the assignment from the parent node, so there's no need to return anything--the new object is created and the `.left`/`.right` property is permanently modified immediately. On the other hand, the strategy in `insertNode2` is to pass the new child back up to the parent function, where it is then set, so there's a need to return state back up to the previous function frame in the stack of function calls in order to make a modification. You could also pass a `parent` parameter to the child call, but this seems like a silly way to do it (among other ways).